# Storing SQL results for use on another webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a form on a webpage which is to be used to filter through a database depending on what the user enters:

[image]

An Ajax call to a database returns the count of properties in real time which are satisfied by the query:

```
$query = "
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
first_page_data 
WHERE 
((((acos(sin((".$lat."*pi()/180)) * sin((`geo_lat1`*pi()/180))+cos((".$lat."*pi()/180)) * cos((`geo_lat1`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$lon."- `geo_lon1`)* pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) * 1.609344) < ".$range."
AND
value_min >= " . $valmin . " 
AND 
value_max <= " . $valmax . " 
AND 
bed_min >= " . $bedmin . " 
AND 
bed_max <= " . $bedmax;

$result = mysql_query($query, $first_data);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $number;
```

This works fine, and all works as I want. However I now want to do "something" with the results (eg show them all in a table when a button is clicked, show them on a google map, etc). How do I store the results of this query for use on another webpage? I cant re-query the database on another page because the results are dependant on the users input on this form.

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` and send a JSON back and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in a temporary session. I actually do not advocate this approach but without knowing your entire env should provide a resolution.

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $first_data);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_SESSION['store'][] = $row;
}
```

I would also highly suggest migrating to using mysqli if you can and once you have finished with this you can wipe it out by using

```
unset($_SESSION['store']);
```

If your result set is massive I do not recommend storing it in a temp session. Store it into a file as a json array.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

file_put_contents($unique_var . '.txt', json_encode($rows));
```

You will need to set a unique value that so you can retrieve the correct file later. Wipe out the file once finished with by using:

```
unlink($unique_var . '.txt');
```

So what about future proofing this? SESSION storage is easier but with a massive result set and a lot of users this could be very resource hungry, so try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $first_data);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows = $row;
}

if(count($rows) < 51) {
    $_SESSION['store'] = $rows;
} else {
    file_put_contents($unique_var . '.txt', $rows);
}
```

And you could later access it like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['store'])) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($unique_var . 'txt');
    unlink($unique_var . '.txt');
} else {
    $contents = $_SESSION['store'];
    unset($_SESSION['store']);
}
```

This way you will always purge the session and temp file as quickly as possible.

Comment: I have a session set up (as the user logs in and then filters their results). So this method your suggesting will store all the results in the session variable? Would it matter if the query returns maybe thousands of results - this would be quite a large array in the session variable!

Comment: Updated my post with a second method to use if your result set is huuuuuge.

Comment: Very useful advice, thankyou. In your opinion what would be the cut-off point for moving from the session method to the separate file? My reason for asking is id be quite happy to limit the results to <50 if this means it could be stored in the session variable. I dont think the user would want to find more than 50 anyway, it wouldnt really be filtering effectively if they did!

Comment: More than 50 results would be the worst filtering ever devised :D Ultimately its upto you. If you are not expecting a high user count then stick with sessions and keep your result set low. You could create an if statement that if your reset set is of a certain size you.... sod it I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a session to store the user's input and then re-query the database. No need to store all of the results in a session.